# how to only have numbers stored in an string array in console application

Tags: c#

So, I am trying to create a pizza ordering program for my school project which requires the customer/user to input their details e.g name phone number address and what not. I store all those information into a string array, but how to I only allow numbers to be entered into the phone number section. I tried using a method which I have been provided with but it doesn't seem to work it just errors.

Here is my current code

```
public static string[] GetCustInfo(string [] custInfo)
    {
        start:
        bool success = false;

        Console.Write("\n" + "Please input D for Delivery OR P for Pickup($3 for Delivery): "  + "\n");
        custInfo[0] = Console.ReadLine();

        while (success != true) 
        {

            if (custInfo[0] == "D" || custInfo[0] == "d")
            {

                custInfo[1] = ReadString("Please enter your name: ");
                Console.Write(Readint("Please enter your Ph No. : "));
                custInfo[2] = Console.ReadLine();
                custInfo[3] = ReadString("Please enter your adress: ");


                success = true;
            }
            else if (custInfo[0] == "P" || custInfo[0] == "p")
            {
                custInfo[1] = ReadString("Please enter your name: ");

                success = true;
            }
            else
            {
                goto start;
            }

        }

        return custInfo;
    }
```

Here are the methods I am using to prevent the user from entering a number or letter:

```
 public static int Readint(String prompt)
    {
        int userInput = 0;
        Boolean success = false;
        while (!success)
        {
            Console.Write(prompt);
            try
            {
                userInput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                success = true;
            }
            catch 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter a VALID NUMBER");
            }
        }
        return userInput;
    }

 public static string ReadString(String prompt)
    {
        string userInput = " ";
        Boolean success = false;
        while (!success)
        {
            Console.Write(prompt);
            try
            {
                userInput = Console.ReadLine();
                if (userInput.Length <= 20 && userInput.Length>1)
                {

                    success = true;

                    foreach (char charcter in userInput)
                    {
                        if (Char.IsNumber(charcter) || Char.IsSymbol(charcter) || Char.IsPunctuation(charcter))
                        {
                            success = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (success == false)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid input!" + "\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    success = true;
                }
            }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        return userInput;
    }
```

I tried inserting:

```
custInfo[2] = Readint("Please enter your Ph No.");
```

but it just gave me an error saying:

> "cannot implicate type int to string"

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but consider replacing the "goto" statement with a slightly refactored loop

Comment: Your pizza better be good for a mandatory $3.00 delivery charge. Most deliver for free. :)

Comment: Its a requirement for a school assignment, not my idea I am just coding it.

Comment: would a try catch be better than goto? instead of looping it back it just prevents the user from continuing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but how to I only allow numbers to be entered into the phone number

You `ReadInt` method already takes care of this point with the while-loop and the try/catch clause. If you want to store this information into the array you need to get your number into the correct/fitting data type for the array saying: `string`. You return value of `ReadInt` is an `int` and this class has an implementation of the [`ToString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/6t7dwaa5(v=vs.110).aspx) method which in your case would convert the `int` into a `string`. So you can simply call it on the returnvalue of `ReadInt`:

```
custInfo[1] = ReadString("Please enter your name: ");
custInfo[2] = Readint("Please enter your Ph No.").ToString(); 
custInfo[3] = ReadString("Please enter your adress: ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Insted of `public static string[] GetCustInfo(string [] custInfo)`, you might add array of an objects, but keep in mind next : Object array store elements of different types in a single collection. An object reference can point to any derived type instance.

Whatever you could do this :

```
object[] array1 = new object[5];
array1[0] = new object();
     array1[1] = new StringBuilder("Initialized");
     array1[2] = "String literal";
     array1[3] = 3;
     array1[4] = null;
```

So in your case: this might look like this

```
public static object[] GetCustInfo(object [] custInfo)
```

Answer (score 0):

You trying to insert an int value into string array..surely make sense that you convert the value into a string?